How to provide a read only or global docker (client) config file?
I meed to deploy a docker (cli) configuration that are common to all users. According to the docs (June 2024), the docker client processes "files" in the config directory specified by DOCKER_CONFIG or --config option. However, other than mentioning "config.json", no other files are specified. Does it process only config.json? Or only json files? Or only specific files?
Although one reads at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#configuration-files the following:

Docker manages most of the files in the configuration directory and you shouldn't modify them. However, you can modify the config.json

The fact is, docker login will actually modify config.json, which can be quite undesirable.
I couldn't find any other official documentation concerning files here. Is there a secret "include" directive, or are other files in the directory processed in a deterministic fashion?

What underlying problem are you trying to solve? https://xyproblem.info/
